# .pythonrc.py not working with Python 2.7 on macOS

Tags: python, bash

This is the content of the `.pythonrc.py` file that I set up on my laptop running Debian testing:

```
import os, readline, rlcompleter, atexit
history_file= os.path.join(os.environ['HOME'], '.python_history')
try:
  readline.read_history_file(history_file)
except IOError:
  pass
readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
readline.parse_and_bind('"\e[A": history-search-backward')
readline.parse_and_bind('"\e[B": history-search-forward')
readline.parse_and_bind('"C-\e[A": reverse-search-history')
readline.parse_and_bind('"C-\e[B": forward-search-history')

readline.set_history_length(8000)
atexit.register(readline.write_history_file, history_file)

del os, readline, rlcompleter, atexit, history_file, __file__
```

I have a copy of the same file into my Macbook running macOs Sierra, combined with a `.profile` file, here attached:

```
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

HISTSIZE=2000
HISTFILESIZE=4000

bind '"\e[A": history-search-backward'
bind '"\e[B": history-search-forward'
bind '"C-\e[A": reverse-search-history'
bind '"C-\e[B": forward-search-history'

alias pythonic='python -i -c "from user import *"'

PYTHONSTARTUP=$HOME/.pythonrc.py
```

Auto-completion and history search work properly on Bash, but the same features seems to not work as expected when running Python through the `pythonic` alias. Can someone explain me the reason of this behavior and how to solve it, if possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in [MacOS](https://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html#module-readline), `readline` moudle use `libedit` instead of `GNU readline`, which has different configuration syntax.

you could install `gnureadline` [package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/gnureadline), or use homebrew to install a new python binary which use `GNU readline`, or change your rc configs.

as you specified `-c 'import user'`, the `user` module looks and execute `.pythonrc.py`, function as `PYTHONSTARTUP` does, so you just need one.

besides, shell variable defined in `~/.profile` is viable within bash process itself, but python runs as a child process of bash, you have to export `PYTHONSTARTUP` to make it available to python:

```
export PYTHONSTARTUP=$HOME/.pythonrc.py
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestion but also exporting the `PYTHONSTARTUP` environment variable, `pythonic` keeps not working.

Comment: try `env | grep 'PYTHONSTARTUP'` to check var exists or not, if not, double check does your `.profile` get executed.

Comment: `grep` returns the variable, so it is defined.

Comment: what about `export -p | grep PYTHON`?

Comment: This latter returns `declare -x PYTHONSTARTUP="/Users/rodolfo/.pythonrc.py"`

Comment: In order to be more precise, arrow up and down work to search history backward and forward, but if I move the cursor to the left or to the right the history is not filtered. Furthermore, auto-completion with Tab doesn't work.

Comment: I have removed the `pythonic` alias from `.profile` and yes, when I launch Python from terminal, the modules included into `.pythonrc.py` are imported by default. Anyway, the listed issues still occur.

Comment: @rudicangiotti updated, in MacOS, python use libedit rather than GNU readline.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'm gonna take a look!

Comment: `readline.parse_and_bind("bind ^I rl_complete")` seems to be okay for Tab completion. Anyway, still not found any solution for filtered search.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest adding your keybindings to `.inputrc`, which is used by any application using the Readline library. Then you don't need to add them to either `.profile` or `.pythonrc.py`.

The format is different (and slightly simpler):

```
"\e[A": history-search-backward
"\e[B": history-search-forward
"C-\e[A": reverse-search-history
"C-\e[B": forward-search-history

set history-size 8000
```

(The Readline library itself doesn't concern itself with reading from or writing to a history file, so that part would need to remain in your Python rc file.)

Comment: The behavior of the Python console keeps to be the same.